# I have a pic 18F4550 how to read distance from ultrasonic sensor

Tags: visual-studio, embedded, microcontroller, sensors, pic

I have PIC 18f4550 and need to write code in picBasic pro.
I'm interfacing DC motors, ultrasonic sensor and IR sensors... etc
I've done everything but still confused of how to interface ultrasonic sensor.

here's ultrasonic pins in PIC

```
trisb.3=0    'trigger ultrasound
trisb.4=1    ' Echo from Ultrasound
```

i need an example code

Comment: Share your code so that we can have better understanding of what you are doing.

Comment: There is no need i gave the ports of ultrasonic i just need a code that returns a distance and i will use it in my code

Comment: This site is for helping. Take reference from Arduino with Ultrasonic Sensor, syntax might be different but logic will be same. You should read Datasheet of ultrasonic sensor, they provide the procedure of using it.

Comment: I know how does it work and what should i do but i have a problem with timers in pic

Comment: Then you add a question like “Problem with timer in PIC 18F”. The more you make other clear what you are looking for the better you get the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Basic Steps to program it :**

1-Provide TRIGGER to ultrasonic module 
2-Listen for Echo 
3-Start Timer when ECHO HIGH is received 
4-Stop Timer when ECHO goes LOW 
5-Read Timer Value 
 
6-Convert it to Distance 
7-Display it

## **Distance Calculation**

- Distance = Speed * Time
- Let d be the distance between Ultrasonic Sensor and Target
- Total distance traveled by the ultrasonic burst : 2d (forward and backward)
- Speed of Sound in Air : 340 m/s = 34000 cm/s
- Thus, d = (34000*Time)/2, where Time = (TMR1H:TMR1L)/(1000000)
- Therefore, d = (TMR1H:TMR1L)/58.82 cm
- TMR1H:TMR1L = TMR1L | (TMR1H<<8)

---

**MikroC Code**

```
// LCD module connections
sbit LCD_RS at RD2_bit;
sbit LCD_EN at RD3_bit;
sbit LCD_D4 at RD4_bit;
sbit LCD_D5 at RD5_bit;
sbit LCD_D6 at RD6_bit;
sbit LCD_D7 at RD7_bit;

sbit LCD_RS_Direction at TRISD2_bit;
sbit LCD_EN_Direction at TRISD3_bit;
sbit LCD_D4_Direction at TRISD4_bit;
sbit LCD_D5_Direction at TRISD5_bit;
sbit LCD_D6_Direction at TRISD6_bit;
sbit LCD_D7_Direction at TRISD7_bit;
// End LCD module connections

void main()
{
  int a;
  char txt[7];
  Lcd_Init();
  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);          // Clear display
  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CURSOR_OFF);     // Cursor off

  TRISB = 0b00010000;           //RB4 as Input PIN (ECHO)

  Lcd_Out(1,1,"Developed By");
  Lcd_Out(2,1,"Mina Karam");

  Delay_ms(3000);
  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);

  T1CON = 0x10;                 //Initialize Timer Module

  while(1)
  {
    TMR1H = 0;                  //Sets the Initial Value of Timer
    TMR1L = 0;                  //Sets the Initial Value of Timer

    PORTB.F0 = 1;               //TRIGGER HIGH
    Delay_us(10);               //10uS Delay
    PORTB.F0 = 0;               //TRIGGER LOW

    while(!PORTB.F4);           //Waiting for Echo
    T1CON.F0 = 1;               //Timer Starts
    while(PORTB.F4);            //Waiting for Echo goes LOW
    T1CON.F0 = 0;               //Timer Stops

    a = (TMR1L | (TMR1H<<8));   //Reads Timer Value
    a = a/58.82;                //Converts Time to Distance
    a = a + 1;                  //Distance Calibration
    if(a>=2 && a<=400)          //Check whether the result is valid or not
    {
      IntToStr(a,txt);
      Ltrim(txt);
      Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
      Lcd_Out(1,1,"Distance = ");
      Lcd_Out(1,12,txt);
      Lcd_Out(1,15,"cm");
    }
    else
    {
      Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
      Lcd_Out(1,1,"Out of Range");
    }
    Delay_ms(400);
  }
}
```